# Default value for a (non-custom) profile field

Tags: wordpress, profile, fields

Is there a way to set a default value for a (non-custom) profile field - that would get pre-populated when the page with the profile opens?
Cheers

Comment: I know hooks (e.g. https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC42/hook_civicrm_buildForm) - but is there another way?

Comment: Would a bit of js be in your skill set?

Comment: Would probably get there - was primarily thinking that I may have missed an on-board way to do so...

Comment: In webforms it is straight forward for core fields (just fyi)

Comment: Yep - but no Drupal ;(

Comment: Have you tried Caldera Forms CiviCRM: https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm

Comment: Wow - on the way to Webforms for Wordpress then! @ChristianWach referencing Javascript and probably using CRM.api3 calls - right!? I've been trying all day (I'm quite persistent without any real skills usually get things to work with trial and error) - but no luck. Would you be able to to provide a sample script (working in the realm of Wordpress - e.g. an API call that outputs the current contacts first name?) I'd promise play around with it! Cheers

Comment: On the way, yes. CFC will allow you to auto-populate a field without the need for code - just check the box and select which value you want from CiviCRM